# Disable autoformat in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to fill a spreadsheet with information about classes (in an educational context)
We have a class named 1AM and it's auto formatted to a datetime.

I have tried to set the column to plain text but it doesn't seem to change the auto formatting.

```
let ssClasses = SpreadsheetApp.create("classes");
let column = ssClasses.getRange("A1:E200");
column.setNumberFormat("@");
```

How to disable auto formatting via Google Apps script in a google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests that can help you with this issue. From what I can see, the result of the format will depend on the type of trigger you are using, and if the code was run before the "1AM" was added or after.

For example, I tested 2 types of onEdit triggers ([Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), and [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable),) and it didn't work as expected for both kind of triggers.

If the user inputs "1AM," Google Sheets will change the format to time format and change it to "1:00 AM;" the edit will trigger the format, and it will change the time format "1:00 AM" to "Plain text." However, this will keep the value as 1:00 AM.

For this function I will recomend to use onOpen instead. Either as a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), or a [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

*Note: Remember this will only affect to all the new values, not the old ones*

Here are 2 sample I tested:

With onEdit():

*Note: As you can see the onEdit doesn't work properly*

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  range.setNumberFormat('@');
}
```

[image: OnEdit gif]

With onOpen():

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ssClasses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("classes3");
  let column = ssClasses.getRange("A1:E200");
  column.setNumberFormat('@');
}
```

[image: onOpen gift]

Comment: There is no `sheet` property in the event object. `@STRING@` is an invalid number format.

Comment: @doubleunary, I change some parts. Sorry, I was testing something else in the code and forgot to remove those parts after the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  if (!e.value || !e.value.match(/^(1:00 AM)$/i)) return;
  e.range.setNumberFormat('@').setValue('1AM');
}
```